# How to configure Adobe Reader with command line or script?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, adobe-reader

Is there possibility to configure Adobe Reader using command line (direct `cmd` or something like that) or `.bat`/`.cmd` script?
**OS:** Windows 7
**Task:** Create script to configure Adobe Reader after installation was completed.

For example, configure:

- Edit > Preferences > Document > Open Settings
- Edit > Preferences > Language > Application Language

Comment: I have updated my answer with another solution (solution 1) which easier way to find the registry changes.

Comment: Do you need more help? If my answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Also see [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I hadn't time to try. I will try this today or tomorrow and then make decision: accept or replay a problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I configure some Adobe Read settings from the command line after installation?

There are no command line switches to configure Adobe Reader settings.

- The available command lines switches are documented at [Command Line Switches - Adobe Reader](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Acrobat) and are for opening and printing pdf files.

There are two solutions using different software to capture the registry changes:

---

#### Solution 1 - Using RegFromApp

1. Download and install [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html).
2. Run Acrobat Reader.
3. Run RegFromApp and select the Acrobat Reader process.
4. Make changes to Acrobat Reader settings.
5. Close Acrobat Reader.
6. In RegFromApp click "File" > "Stop" or press <kbd>F8</kbd>
7. Copy registry changes and save in a `.reg` file.
8. Use [regedit](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) in your batch file to import the `.reg` file containing your configuration changes.

---

#### Solution 2 - Using Process Monitor

1. Download and install [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).
2. Run Process Monitor and start logging registry changes
3. Run Adobe Reader and make your changes through the GUI.
4. Stop the Process Monitor registry logging.
5. Use the log file to find out which registry entries have been added or changed.
6. Open the registry using the registery editor and export the added/changed entries to a `.reg` file.
7. Use [regedit](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) in your batch file to import the `.reg` file containing your configuration changes.

---

#### What is RegFromApp?

> RegFromApp monitors the Registry changes made by the application that you selected, and creates a standard RegEdit registration file (.reg) that contains all the Registry changes made by the application. You can use the generated .reg file to import these changes with RegEdit when it's needed.
>
> [image]

Source [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html)

---

#### What is Process Monitor?

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.
>
> - It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements
>   including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event
>   properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process
>   information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for
>   each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more.
> - Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.

Source [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) or [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.
- [regedit](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) - Import, export or delete registry settings from a text (.REG) file.
- [regedit](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/82821)  - Command-line switches.